# Is there a way to use a variable defined in another Python file?

Tags: python

Currently, I have two Python files, which are separate:

**functions.py**

```
def get_file():
    ...
    file = /Users/.../file2.txt  # different every time
    return file
...
```

**test.py**

```
def use_file():
    # processes using the file path from get_file()
```

It seems a bit odd to have them separate here because the purposes of the functions aren't clear, but I was wondering, in general, if there was any way to have a variable of this scope or a way to pass the variable in this situation.

Comment: See this: [import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: in `test.py` you can do: `from functions import get_file` to use the function. If the variable is declared globally in the `function` file you can also: `from functions import file`. But without actual initialization to the file and guidance what you are trying to achieve. it will be a bit harder to tell you what exactly to use and do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they are in the same directory you can use something like this

```
#file 1
def var():
    #code in here
    return var
```

and

```
#file 2
import file1
var = file1.var()
```